# unix command to replace anything between between two delimiter positions

Tags: linux

Please help me with a unix command to replace anything between two delimiter positions.
For ex: I have multiple files with below header data and I want replace the data between * delimiters at 9th and 10th  position

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*80881          *ZZ*TNC0022        *190115*1237*^*00501*000320089*0*P*|~
```

My output should like this:

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*80881          *ZZ*TNC0022        *190327*1237*^*00501*000320089*0*P*|~
```

Comment: You should provide some simpler sample input/output that you will elaborate for this very particular case. This way, it will be more accurate for others users when searching the same response and you will be able to transpose the logic to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
perl -pe 's/^((?:[^*]*\*){9})([^*]+)(.*)/${1}190327$3/'
```

The regexp searches for 9 occurences `{9}` of anything but not being a star `[^*]` followed by a star `\*` and stores all in the first capture group. The second capture is at least one character not being a star `[^*]+`. And the third capture is the rest of the line.

A matching line gets replaced by the first part `${1}`, your new value `190327` and the third part `$3`.